# Which is correct: "confirm with somebody" or "confirm to somebody"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

I want to talk to someone and make sure something is done. How to express this meaning using the word *confirm*? I'm not sure whether it should be *confirm **to** sb* or *confirm **with** sb*. Is there another way to say it?

Comment: Please make an effort to find an answer or some clues and let us know what you found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*With* is correct:

> I'd like to confirm with you that you will finish the report by Thursday.

You can also request confirmation:

> Please confirm that you'll finish the report by then.
>   I need your confirmation that you'll do it on time.

With this sense, you can also confirm something *for* someone:

> Let me look at my calendar to confirm that for you.

That is, to act on their request for confirmation.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are three distinct meanings for "confirm":

- "get confirmation from"
- "give confirmation to"
- "mutually reach a firm agreement from some more vague state"

I think all of them can use "with" (which can therefore sometimes be ambiguous). The second can also use "to".

Comment: Regarding the first one, can you tell me which one is more correct or just correct: "I will confirm this by Tom", "I will confirm this with Tom".

Comment: I would not say "confirm ... by", and if I heard it I would think the speaker was not a native English speaker.

Comment: @ColinFine Is it correct to use from after confirm, e.g., I wanted to confirm it from experts?

Comment: @user343802: that is clear, but not idiomatic. Normally I would say "with experts", and rely on the meaning of "expert" to select the first of my three meanings. If I wanted to avoid that ambiguity, I would say "get confirmation from experts".

Comment: @ColinFine Many thanks.